# Springboot java @CrossOrigin doesn't work as it should work, why must I do extra configurations when this annotation Is present?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:3000") 
@RequestMapping(value="", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Client>> getAllClients(/*@RequestParam("page") int page, @RequestParam("size") int size*/) {

    List<Client> clientList = services.getClientsList(/*page,size*/);
    if(clientList != null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(clientList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }else{
        return  new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

If spring  boot  provided **@CrossOrigin**,  why  doesn't  it work as it  should?

Thanks,

In advance...

Comment: Yes , it's running on 3000 and it's not receivin data back ...Instead I get Options 401... yes this means am trying to access a protected resource when am not authorised... but why is it so when @CrossOrigin is meant to address this issue ? Am using 5.0.8 Release

Comment: Yes I have spring security dependancy in my POM File

Comment: Sorry I meant to remove the spring security dependency if not configured

Comment: When I remove that dependancy I will not be able to hash passwords ... how can I get around that...?

Comment: I comprehend man ... sorry for that...; does 401 occur in production?

Comment: please add your WebSecurityConfig and your pom to the question

Answer (score 1):

So Spring security and @CrossOrigin annotation don't talk to eachother.

you need to configure the CORS for spring security too.

As you can find in the [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html):

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            // by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource
            .cors().and()
            ...
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can try with a globla config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

this is for all origin, good for dev

Answer (score -1):

I disabled Web security  on chrome... It gives me 200 status code ... see stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/